# How to get OS Version through Powershell with WMI?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, wmi

Does anybody know how to get the OS Version like this:

[OS Version: 1607](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZc9N.png)

With using Get-WmiObject? 
Couldn't find this Informatin at all..

Comment: What is the reason you are using Powershell?

Comment: I have to implement this information in a desktop information software and the only way I can do this is with an .ini file and a WMI query

Comment: The powershell tag is still unclear, nevertheless: `(Get-Item "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion").GetValue('ReleaseID')`

Comment: Have you tried `(Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).Version`?

Comment: @Sandeep Version will get you the ID Microsoft uses to identify their Windows version (version 6.1 is used for Windows 7, version 6.2 is used for Windows 10, ...)

Answer (score 11):

Isn't a simple answer to the original question as follows:

`Get-ComputerInfo  | select windowsversion`

`WindowsVersion`

`--------------`

`1903`

Comment: And to do it against other PCs in the same domain when you have Admin rights, use "Invoke-Command -ComputerName PCNAME {Get-ComputerInfo | select windowsversion}"

Comment: That assumes you also have remote PowerShell access.

Comment: I'm running Windows 10 22H2, and running `Get-ComputerInfo  | select windowsversion` incorrectly reports I'm running `2009` - this is because `Get-ComputerInfo` only reads from `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ReleaseId` which should not be used for post-2020 builds of Windows because those should use `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\DisplayVersion` instead.

Answer (score 3):

The OS version is stored in a Registry Key: **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ReleaseId**. Normally you can read those keys using WMI.

[LotPings](https://superuser.com/users/639112/lotpings) has provided the correct query in the comments: `(Get-Item "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion").GetValue('ReleaseID')`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little script I wrote to find computer information:

## Powershell: Get Computer Info

```
$Computer = "localhost"
$Manufacturer = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Computer -class win32_computersystem | select -ExpandProperty Manufacturer
$Model = Get-WmiObject -class win32_computersystem -ComputerName $Computer | select -ExpandProperty model
$Serial = Get-WmiObject -class win32_bios -ComputerName $Computer | select -ExpandProperty SerialNumber
$wmi_os = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Computer | select CSName,Caption,Version,OSArchitecture,LastBootUptime
switch($wmi_os.Version){
'10.0.10240'{$wmi_build="1507"}
'10.0.10586'{$wmi_build="1511"}
'10.0.14393'{$wmi_build="1607"}
'10.0.15063'{$wmi_build="1703"}
'10.0.16299'{$wmi_build="1709"}
'10.0.17134'{$wmi_build="1803"}
'10.0.17686'{$wmi_build="1809"}
}
$wmi_cpu = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Processor -ComputerName $Computer | select -ExpandProperty DataWidth
$wmi_memory = Get-WmiObject -class cim_physicalmemory -ComputerName $Computer | select Capacity | %{($_.Capacity / 1024kb)}
$DNName = Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -like '$Computer'" | select -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName
$Boot=[System.DateTime]::ParseExact($($wmi_os.LastBootUpTime).Split(".")[0],'yyyyMMddHHmmss',$null)
[TimeSpan]$uptime = New-TimeSpan $Boot $(get-date)
Write-Host "------Computer Info for $Computer------------------`r"
Write-Host "Hostname from WMI`: $($wmi_os.CSName)"
Write-Host "$DNName"
Write-Host "$Manufacturer $Model SN`:$Serial"
Write-Host "$($wmi_os.Caption) $wmi_build $($wmi_os.OSArchitecture) $($wmi_os.Version)"
Write-Host "CPU Architecture: $wmi_cpu"
Write-Host "Memory: $wmi_memory"
Write-Host "Uptime`: $($uptime.days) Days $($uptime.hours) Hours $($uptime.minutes) Minutes $($uptime.seconds) Seconds"
Write-Host "--------------------------------------------------------"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not through the WMI, but [Jeff Mercado](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390278/jeff-mercado) **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7330368/505701)** might be to any help anyhow;

Since you have access to the .NET library, you could access the [`OSVersion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion.aspx) property of the [`System.Environment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.aspx) class to get this information. For the version number, there is the `Version` property.

For example,

```
PS C:\> [System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
6      1      7601   65536
```

Details of Windows versions can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724833%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Get-WmiObject can give you the build version and Number like

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).Version
```

Or

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).BuildNumber
```

If you want a more general information about just the OS, Id rather suggest you using the Get-Item cmdlet, and search "ProductName" and not "relaseID" key as mentioned above.

```
(Get-Item "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion").GetValue('ProductName')
```

The cool thing is that those commands will work with windows 7 up to Windows 10  and Server 2012 up to 2019. It's useful if you need to get information about workstations or apply tasks on workstations in a hybrid environment.

Answer (score 0):

It's not using Get-WmiObject, but check this out:

> Get-ComputerInfo | Select-Object @{Name='Operating System';Expression={$*.OsName}}, @{Name='Version';Expression={$*.WindowsVersion}}, @{Name='Build';Expression={$*.OsBuildNumber}}, @{Name='Architecture';Expression={$*.OsArchitecture}}, @{Name='System Root';Expression={$*.WindowsSystemRoot}}, @{Name='Language';Expression={$*.OsLanguage}}, @{Name='Boot State';Expression={$_.CsBootupState}} | Format-Table

or

> Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion' | Select-Object ProductName, ReleaseID, CurrentBuild, SystemRoot

or

Simply take my program and run with it. I'm working on a new version already and hope to have it released soon, as the new version uses a lot more PowerShell and a lot less WMIC commands.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/signature-by-mafii/files/

Answer (score 0):

For output similar to what you would see in System Information here's an expansion of the comment from [LotPings](https://superuser.com/users/639112/lotpings) and called out in answer from [marijnr](https://superuser.com/users/891138/marijnr)
Example Output:
Windows 10 Enterprise 22H2 - 19045.3570

```
$osVersionInfo = Get-Item "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion"
$osProductName = $osVersionInfo.GetValue("ProductName")
$osDisplayVersion = $osVersionInfo.GetValue("DisplayVersion")
$osCurrentBuild = $osVersionInfo.GetValue("CurrentBuild")
$osUbr = $osVersionInfo.GetValue("UBR")

$osVersion = $osProductName + " " + $osDisplayVersion + " - " + $osCurrentBuild + "." + $osUbr
```

Answer (score -1):

Found this cool script at TechNet Gallary: [Get-WindowsVersion](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Get-WindowsVersion-can-0726c5d4)

Here is how it looks:

```
[19JUN] :>Get-WindowsVersion -ComputerName ktpc

ComputerName Productname           WindowsVersion WindowsBuild   ProductID               InstallTime
------------ -----------           -------------- ------------   ---------               -----------
KTPC         Windows 10 Enterprise 1803           10.0.17134.112 00329-10280-00000-AA451 5/22/2018 8:10:15 AM
```

It utilizes the same "RealseID" as others suggested to get this value. However, it is nice effort and ready to use.

Answer (score -1):

On Windows 11:

```
(gin).OSDisplayVersion
```

On Windows 10:

```
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v DisplayVersion
```

this will show 22H2, which is last version of Windows 10:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/announcements/windows-10-22h2-end-of-support-update